# Is there is any way to increase the java heap size in nokia c2 mobiles?

Tags: java-me, nokia, mobile-application, nokia-s40

I'm developing a mobile app in J2ME. I'm facing memory issues. I'm using Nokia c2 mobile.Please tell me Is there is any way to increase the java heap size in Nokia c2 mobiles?

Thanks & Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to extend VM memory heap size on mobile devices. There are significant constraints and mobile developers have to deal with them.